# Method with @JmsListener not executed when setting custom message converter

Tags: converters, message, spring-jms

Hy,

Having these three classes I have found a problem:

```
package xpadro.spring.jms;


import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;





@SpringBootApplication
public class JmsJavaconfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JmsJavaconfigApplication.class, args);
    }




    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller(){
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        Class array[] = new Class[1];
        array[0]= xpadro.spring.jms.model.Order.class;      
        jaxb.setClassesToBeBound(array);
        return jaxb;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MarshallingMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter( Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller){
        MarshallingMessageConverter mc = new MarshallingMessageConverter();     
        mc.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        mc.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);     
        return mc;      
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JmsTemplate init(MarshallingMessageConverter messageConverter,ConnectionFactory  connectionFactory){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter); 
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    } 


}
```

Next, the model:

```
package xpadro.spring.jms.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "order")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -797586847427389162L;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String id="";

    public Order() {

    }

    public Order(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Next, the listener:

```
package xpadro.spring.jms.listener;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import xpadro.spring.jms.model.Order;
import xpadro.spring.jms.service.StoreService;

@Component
public class SimpleListener {
    private final StoreService storeService;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleListener(StoreService storeService) {
        this.storeService = storeService;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "simple.queue")
    public void receiveOrder(Order order) {
        storeService.registerOrder(order);
    }
}
```

The class that sends messages:

```
package xpadro.spring.jms.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import xpadro.spring.jms.model.Order;

@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {
    private static final String SIMPLE_QUEUE = "simple.queue";
    private static final String IN_QUEUE = "in.queue";

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ClientServiceImpl(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        //MessageRegistered with a bean
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(SIMPLE_QUEUE, order);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerOrder(Order order) {
        //MessageRegistered with a bean
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(IN_QUEUE, order);
    }
}
```

The point is that listener(method receiveOrder()) is not executed when I set a custom message converter in the class JmsJavaconfigApplication. When I dont set it, spring boot sets a SimpleMessageConverter and the listener is executed.

Any wrong or missed configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an marshalling converter to the `@JmsListener` to unmarshall the message, by configuring the listener container factory [see the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated).

Comment: Thanks, it worked!. I think Spring boot creates a DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory with a default converted called "SimpleMessageConverter" and thats why it didnt work for me

Comment: Yes; that's one of the benefits of boot - it creates a set of default beans (by default), to simplify configuration of many applications. When you need extra features, you simply override those beans where you need different configuration, such as this.

Comment: Can you please update the link to the doc? says invalid :)

Comment: Thanks; I fixed the link.