# Amazon SQS Async Listener for the Extended Client Library using Spring JmsListener

Tags: java, asynchronous, listener, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

My team is trying to implement an Async Listener for the [Amazon SQS Java Extended Client Library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/), because as noted on [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/issues/5) and [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/167) links, there isn't going to be any support any time soon.

The original problem is that we need to send a very large payload through SQS. So to solve this, we used the aforementioned Amazon SQS Java Extended Client Library functionality. It would automatically upload large payloads to S3, and later on retrieve them as messages without the consumer ever worrying how to retrieve them from S3. Sadly this can only be done synchronously out of the box.

So to make it work asynchronously we've come up with the following code using the [JmsListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html). It works, and we obtain the serialized object in String format.

> AWS/SQS Beans

```
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClient;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ExtendedClientConfiguration;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ProviderConfiguration;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;

@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        jmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return jmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        final ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfig = new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
                .withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(amazonS3Client, "my-bucket-name");

        final ProviderConfiguration providerConfiguration = new ProviderConfiguration();
        providerConfiguration.setNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10);

        final SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(providerConfiguration,
                new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(amazonSqs, extendedClientConfig));

        return sqsConnectionFactory
    }
}
```

> The Listener that uses the `@JmsListener` annotation:

```
@Component
public class QueueListener {

    ...

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-queue-name", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeMessage(String queueMessage) {
        System.out.println(queueMessage);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that **although** it works, large messages read from S3 come as a `String`. We would *really really really* like the messages were automatically parsed into a specific object (like the `@SqsListener` already allows us to, without us having to parse the string ourselves), like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "my-queue-name", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeMessage(SomeObject queueMessage) ...
```

There is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997479/method-with-jmslistener-not-executed-when-setting-custom-message-converter), but the answer's link is dead, and the description does nothing for us. And [this JMS messaging guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) wouldn't work well in conjunction with the SQS Extended Library. To make things a bit harder, we can only use the `org.springframework.jms.support.converter` classes when setting the converter to the `jmsListenerContainerFactory`, so we cant use the same Jackson mappers AWS uses.

Comment: i have a similar thing to implement. Do you have a specific maven dependencies that worked for you.  i have some issue with some of the method deprecated and doesn't accept AmazonS3Client and AmazonSQSAsync