# How to use AWS SQSExtendedClient library to make it work asynchrously using JMSListener java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, sqslistener

Am trying to achieve exactly what the below link is trying to do.

[Amazon SQS Async Listener for the Extended Client Library using Spring JmsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751378/amazon-sqs-async-listener-for-the-extended-client-library-using-spring-jmslisten)

I couldn't find AmazonS3Client and AmazonSQSAsync class using below example. Did any get to this point ?

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    final ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfig = new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
            .withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(amazonS3Client, "my-bucket-name");

    final ProviderConfiguration providerConfiguration = new ProviderConfiguration();
    providerConfiguration.setNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10);

    final SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(providerConfiguration,
            new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(amazonSqs, extendedClientConfig));

    return sqsConnectionFactory
}
```

Could someone help answering this question. Is there similar thing anyone faced ?
Help Appreciated!